# Selenium web scraping is returning null values

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to use selenium to scrape names off of a betting site (https://www.oddschecker.com/us/baseball/mlb) along with odds for each name. The names work fine, but the odds for each name drop off around six names in and then begin to alternate.

The code:

```
'url = 'https://www.oddschecker.com/us/baseball/mlb'
parent_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="S7oyZN"]')

games = parent_element.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_2tehgH"]')
scores = parent_element.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="odds-primary"]')


for game, score in zip(games, scores):
    print(f"{game.text}: {score.text}")
```

```
returns: 

Boston Red Sox: -107
@ Tampa Bay Rays: -115
Cincinnati Reds: +102
@ Atlanta Braves: +123
Seattle Mariners: -120
@ Chicago Cubs: -117
New York Yankees: 
@ Cleveland Guardians: 
Oakland Athletics: 
@ Baltimore Orioles: -107
Houston Astros: 
@ Pittsburgh Pirates: -115
Miami Marlins: 
@ Philadelphia Phillies: +155

etc etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can try to fix the problem,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = 'https://www.oddschecker.com/us/baseball/mlb'
driver.get(url)

parent_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="S7oyZN"]')
for element in parent_elements:
    games = element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'li').find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div._2tehgH')
    scores = element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'li').find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="third-bet-column"]').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')

    for game, score in zip(games, scores):
        score = score.text.split('\n')[-1]
        print(f"{game.text}: {score}")
```

output:

```
St Louis Cardinals: -108
@ Colorado Rockies: +110
Washington Nationals: -104
@ Los Angeles Angels: +112
Milwaukee Brewers: -135
@ Arizona Diamondbacks: +128
Los Angeles Dodgers: +100
@ San Francisco Giants: +117
New York Yankees: +100
@ Cleveland Guardians: -104
Oakland Athletics: +160
@ Baltimore Orioles: +194
Boston Red Sox: +116
@ Tampa Bay Rays: -107
Detroit Tigers: -105
@ Toronto Blue Jays: +100
Cincinnati Reds: +102
@ Atlanta Braves: -110
Seattle Mariners: +100
@ Chicago Cubs: -118
```

I hope this answers your question.